# How extract specific URLs using Power Automate?

Tags: power-automate

I'd like to extract URLs just under "Open" using Microsoft Power Automate.
In this example, I need to extract only `https://test.com/a` and `https://test.com/b`
Do you know how to do that?

```
Open
[https://test.com/a]

Open
[https://test.com/b]


[https://test.com/c]
```

Comment: How is the data being stored/how is the data coming into PowerApps? The snippet you included doesn't look like any format I know of, unless the data is just straight text.

Answer (score 0):

You can  user Parserr within Microsoft Power Automate. Parserr will allow you to create a customized set of rules, in which you can indicate specific conditions e.g.

- "Get all text after: Open[" and "Get all text before: ]".

Like this:
[image: Create rule for Parserr1]